# How to Get Mocktail to Accept URL Parameters

Tags: ios, mocking, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using Square's Mocktail library in my iOS project: https://github.com/square/objc-mocktail. It works great for one scenario to match the URL exactly, but I'm interested in having different Mocktail responses based on different scenarios:

Success use-case - loginSuccess.tail:

```
POST
myurl.com?username="myusername"&password="mypassword"
200
application/json

{ Success Response JSON here }
```

Wrong Credentials use-case - loginWrongCredentials.tail:

```
POST
myurl.com?username="badusername"&password="badpassword"
400
application/json

{ Error Response JSON here }
```

It doesn't seem like mocktail gets the parameters. I think it's getting called before the parameters are added to the URL. Has anyone tried this successfully or is there a better iOS library for doing a more "smart" URL mocking?

Answer (score 2):

Line 2 is a regular expression, not an exact URL. Try escaping the question mark:

```
myurl.com\?username=badusername&password=badpassword
```

But if you're trying to match POST data, this won't work, since the POST data isn't in the URL. You probably want your tests to append something generic to the URL like "?test1" or "?test2" or something.